# schedule api request and save to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, rest, schedule

I try to scrape data from an api. I want to schedule this task so it requests the api every half an hour and saves appends the result to a dataframe. However the api response is a nested dictionary so i have to do some parsing. I read that I should lists instead of dataframes to append the data in the function. My Code so far looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import schedule
import time

resp = requests.get(url).json()
df=[]
def fetch_here():
        global df
        r2=json_normalize(resp,record_path=["RWS","RW"])
        r=json_normalize(resp["RWS"],record_path=["RW","FIS","FI"])
        r1=json_normalize(resp["RWS"],record_path=["RW","FIS","FI","CF"])
        workFrame = pd.concat([r, r1], axis=1, sort=False)
        workFrame = workFrame.drop(['SHP',"CF","SSS.SS"], 1)
        time=r2["PBT"]
        workFrame["Time"]=time
        workFrame=workFrame.fillna(method="ffill")
        df=df.append(workFrame)

#Time
schedule.every(30).minutes.do(fetch_here)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

However I get the error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df' referenced before assignment`.
I guess it would be better to store the parsing result as a list and then append?
But I don't know how to normalize the json to a list. 
Hope someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: your `df` is normal list and list.append() doesn't return new value but `None` so your `df=df.append()` may works as `df=None`

Comment: if you want to fethe it in every 30 minutes then you should run `requests.get(url).json()` inside `fetch_here()`. Current code get data from url only once and later it use the same data in `fetch_here()` again and again.